# OnClick is called instead of onLongClick

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I am facing this problem only in **moto g 2nd generation device**. This code works perfectly fine on other devices.

I have implemented `onClick` and `onLongClick` inside adapter on items of lisview. But when I long click on any item, onClick is called instead of onLongClick. 
onClick is also called if I scroll the list view slowly.

Code inside `getView()` is below:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        lifeActionObj = actionList.get(position);

        View v = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_action, null);

        TextView actionNameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.action_name);
        ImageView actionIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.action_icon);
        final Button aInfoBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.action_info);
        final Button aPickBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.action_pick);



        final int actionLocked = lifeActionObj.isLocked();


        aPickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(actionLocked ==1)
                {
                    diplayDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    LifeUser lifeUser = new LifeUser();
                    try {
                        LifeAction lifeActionObj = actionList.get(position);
                        int result = lifeUser.addHabit(traitId, lifeActionObj);

                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    actionActivity.finish();
                }
            }
        });

        aInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(actionLocked ==1)
                {
                    diplayDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent in = new Intent(actionActivity,
                            DisplayHtmlActivity.class);
                    try
                    {
                        in.putExtra("title", actionList.get(position).getDisplayName());
                        in.putExtra("fileName", actionList.get(position).getActionInfoFileName(actionActivity.getLifeTraitObject().getTraitId())+".html");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    actionActivity.startActivity(in);
                }
            }
        });

        final ViewGroup parent1 = parent;
        final View ex = v;

        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(actionActivity, "on click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(actionActivity.getActionMode() != null)
                {
                    actionActivity.getActionMode().finish();
                }

                if(actionLocked == 1)
                {
                    diplayDialog();
                }
            }
        });


        v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(actionActivity, "on long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(actionLocked == 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ex.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    ex.setLongClickable(false);
                    ex.setClickable(false);
                    parent1.setClickable(false);
                    aInfoBtn.setClickable(false);
                    aPickBtn.setClickable(false);
                    final int traitPosition = position;

                    try {
                        actionActivity.startActionMode(new LifeCAB(
                                ex,
                                parent1,
                                traitPosition,
                                aInfoBtn,
                                aPickBtn,
                                actionList.get(position).getDisplayName()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }
        });

        return v;
```

Can anyone tell me what can be the cause of this? Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment or MainActivity , implement it with OnLongClickListener

// Fragment in my case

```
public class Returning extends Fragment implements OnLongClickListener
```

On implementing it, it will ask you to override

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    return true;
}
```

Then inside oncreateview(In case of fragment) or oncreate in case of activity do this

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

Tried this and it is working for me

Comment: This code works fine for all the mobiles except moto g 2nd generation.

Comment: ok actually i am not having moto g so c'nt figure out the real cause of such a behavior. Well let us know when you found the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnTouchListener instead of OnClick and OnLongClick. It will take you a field for work inside adapter.
Also for ListView you should use OnItemLongClickListener and OnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below lines of code and  try to understand logic, you have to return true in onlongclick.

```
item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


item.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't find any change. Above code also returns true. Also this code is not working only for moto g 2nd generation device.